# Create own widget that can interpret html inside

Tags: gwt

I want to create own widget that will be able to interpret the text between start and end tag, eg:

```
<p1:Btn ui:field="open" >Open</p1:Btn>
```

Now the UI binder throws error:

```
Unexpected text in element: "Open" Element <p1:Btn ui:field='open'> (:44)
```

I supose that the widget have to be somehow marked to allow elements inside. 
The second thing is how read the element between tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your widget needs simply implement the [HasText](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HasText.html) interface.

Comment: Or `HasHTML` if your widget accepts HTML: `<p1:Btn>Open <i>this</i>!</p1:Btn>`. Beware that `setText` can receive a `<` or `&` that will have to be HTML-escaped if you use the value as HTML (have a look at `SafeHtmlUtils` to build your widget's content); e.g. `<p1:Btn>&lt;Open&gt;</p1:Btn>` will pass `"<Open>"` to `setText` if the widget is `HasText`, it'll however give `"&lt;Open&gt;"` to `setHTML` if it implements `HasHTML`.